# Scroll to Top Not Working on Wordpress Theme

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, anchor

Scroll to top is not working. Not with regular HTML anchors or jQuery!?

http://yinnette.com/verifip/

Any ideas, Im guessing there is a script out there shutting it off?

Thanks! 
Yinnette

Answer (score 0):

This html anchor doesnt work?? 
I didnt see any `<a name="tag"></a>` in your page source.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/k6Hs3/

```
<a name="back_to_top"></a>

TOP<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />

<a href="#back_to_top">Back to top</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your wordpress application it uses  **jQuery JavaScript Library v1.10.2** and you're having these errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.min.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'chrome' of undefined tc-scripts.min.js:1
```

Either fix these errors or use older version of jquery. ex: jquery ver 1.7.2 where it supports msie etc properties are defined.